# Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials facing problem

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

```
curl --location 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tentId/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=xxxxxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=User.Read profile openid email' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=ravindra1437_outlook.com#EXT#@ravinavyamullamurioutlook.onmicrosoft.com'\
--data-urlencode 'password=xxxxxxxxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx'
```

Hi Team, I have facing using the above curl based call i am passing coreect username and password but facing below issue.

{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.\r\nTrace ID: bb4dd885-c0a7-4985-8d95-45c520710800\r\nCorrelation ID: 7eb0748c-6450-462d-8cd5-c48cd869d59c\r\nTimestamp: 2023-04-20 04:07:49Z",
"error_codes": [
50126
],
"timestamp": "2023-04-20 04:07:49Z",
"trace_id": "bb4dd885-c0a7-4985-8d95-45c520710800",
"correlation_id": "7eb0748c-6450-462d-8cd5-c48cd869d59c",
"error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50126"
}

Comment: Seems you are using personal account created by invitation which causing th issue. You must use tenant specific account not invited or personal account for [`ROPC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

Comment: @RavindraBabu, personal accounts that are invited to an Azure AD tenant can't use the ROPC flow. You have to change `username` and `password` with **local** Azure AD user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc),

> The Microsoft identity platform only supports the ROPC grant within Azure AD tenants, not personal accounts. Personal accounts that are invited to an Azure AD tenant can't use the ROPC flow.

I registered one Azure AD application and added same **API permissions** as below:

[image]

When I ran the curl command by importing it in Postman, I got **same error** as I used external user credentials like below:

```
curl --location 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<appID>' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=User.Read profile openid email' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=demouser_gmail.com#EXT#@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
--data-urlencode 'password=xxxxxxxxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx'
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to change  `username`  and  `password`  with  **local**  Azure AD user credentials like below:

```
curl --location 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<appID>' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=User.Read profile openid email' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=demouser@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com
--data-urlencode 'password=xxxxxxxxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx'
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/), I got  **`scp`** claim with added permissions successfully like below:

[image]